# Clarification :MVC,MVP,MVVM

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, mvp

I am reading the difference between MVC,MVP,MVVM

Source: [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dlussier/archive/2009/11/21/136454.aspx)

[image]

My doubt is ,the diagrams (MVP) (MVVM) show  bidirectional arrow between Modle and Presenter,Model and ViewModel.

Presenter and ViewModel obviously aware of Model.But does it mean  Model is aware of Presenter and ViewModel?

Comment: in MVC pt 3 says View does not have any knowledge about controller. Pt 4 says view has knowledge about controller. It contradicts. Pt 4 should be view has knowledge about the model instead. Pls confirm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Presenter and ViewModel obviously aware of Model.But does it mean Model is aware of Presenter and ViewModel?

No.  At least, the way I view these patterns, the Model should (ideally) be unaware of anything except itself.  I tried to highlight that in [my discussion of MVVM](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/06/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-part-7-mvvm/) by only showing a uni-directional arrow to the Model.

However, many people use an arrow going both ways to/from the Model to represent events raised by the Model.  It somewhat depends on how you see this - the Model will likely need to notify other layers of changes within itself.  Depending on the language/framework, this may look like the model "talking" to other layers.  However, I try to be very careful to keep this completely neutral from the Model's point of view.  For example, in C#, I just use an event, where the types are all Model-specific.  It knows "something" may be listening to the event, but does not have any knowledge of what comprises that "something".

Comment: @Reed Wow your discussion is good,how did i miss such good discussion.Thank you.Now things are clear.

Comment: @Reed "It knows "something" may be listening to the event, but does not have any knowledge of what comprises that "something"- Do you mean INotifyPropertyChanged here?

Comment: @ASP.netBeginner: Thanks!  That whole series gets pretty good feedback for people coming from windows forms, at least ;)

Comment: @ASP.netBeginner: I could be INotifyPropertyChanged, or a custom event of some other form.  Any means the model has to notify that data is changing, or that an event occurs, is basically propogating information OUT of the model.... This, in some people's view, means putting an arrow out of the model.  Personally, I still see this as self-contained, but that's my view on it. (Which is why I make the arrow one-way...)

Comment: @Reed Thank you very much for spending your time to give detailed explanation.